# SwiftUI can not open detail screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying some simple app that has a List of items, and needs to open a Detail view, the setup looks like this:

```
var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section {
                List {
                    ForEach(range, id: \.self) { number in
                        NavigationLink(
                          destination: DetailView(city: cities[number])) {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text("\(cities[number].name), \(cities[number].country)")
                                Text("lat:\(cities[number].coord.lat)  lon:\(cities[number].coord.lon)").font(.footnote).foregroundColor(.gray)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Button(action: loadMore) {
                        Text("")
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime(uptimeNanoseconds: 10)) {
                            self.loadMore()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("City list")
        .onTapGesture { UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to:nil, from:nil, for:nil) }
    }
}
```

The code compiles and runs, the List has little pointer on the right, but trying to open it doesn't work. I need the VStack to place two items vertically in one cell. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately your code was not compilable...so i had to comment out a lot ...but this works here:

```
struct DetailView : View {

    var body: some View {

        Text("Detail")
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {

    var data = ["a", "b", "c"]

    var body: some View {


        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    List {
                        ForEach(data, id: \.self) { number in
                            NavigationLink(
                            destination: DetailView()) {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                    Text("a")
                                    Text("b").font(.footnote).foregroundColor(.gray)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                            //                    Button(action: loadMore) {
                            //                        Text("")
                            //                    }
                            .onAppear {
                                //                        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime(uptimeNanoseconds: 10)) {
                                //                            self.loadMore()
                                //                        }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! the real issue is the tap gesture, when I comment it out it works. Maybe you know how I can keep both tap gesture and make a cell clicked?

Comment: can you explain a bit more why you need a tapgesture on your cell and cell tap?

Comment: I have a search bar, so when user taps anywhere outside of keyboard, I'd like to dismiss the keyboard, which I do with tap gesture

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61353984/swift-ui-need-to-keep-both-navigationlink-to-detail-view-and-tap-gesture-recogni

Answer (score 0):

Found it, maybe someone in the future will face it as well: 
I added a tap gesture observer, to toggle keyboard when tapped outside ot if, and this gesture was consumed by that observer thus not letting the cell to be pressed.